# Why does standard error of mean change depending on how measurements are pooled into samples?

Tags: inference, descriptive-statistics, standard-error, computational-statistics

I'm trying to understand why the standard error of the mean changes depending on how measurements are pooled into samples, even if the total measurements are the same.

For example, the following two calculations of the standard error of the mean are giving me different results, despite having the same number of measurements. In the first case, four samples of 30 measurements are taken, and the standard error of the mean is calculated (4 samples, 120 total measurements). In the second case, all four samples are pooled and the SEM is calculated (1 sample, 120 total measurements). Why do these two calculations give different results? All measurements are independent, so that shouldn't be an issue. Thanks!

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
pickups = np.random.randint(0,500 , size=10000)
sample = np.random.choice(pickups, size=30)
sample2 = np.random.choice(pickups, size=30)
sample3 = np.random.choice(pickups, size=30)
sample4 = np.random.choice(pickups, size=30)
mean1 = np.mean(sample)
mean2 = np.mean(sample2)
mean3 = np.mean(sample3)
mean4 = np.mean(sample4)

print(np.std([mean1,mean2,mean3,mean4])/np.sqrt(len(sample)))
print(np.mean((int(mean1),int(mean2),int(mean3),int(mean4))))

3.6237398831512095
243.5

fullsample = np.concatenate((sample,sample2,sample3,sample4))
print(np.std(fullsample)/(np.sqrt(len(fullsample))))
print(np.mean(fullsample))

12.310141389054737
244.01666666666668
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you assume some kind of linearity for a standard error. Squares in the definition of variance (which is a part of a standard error) "kill" all hope for a simple formula. Independence does not mean the sample covariance is zero.